# PHP Fatal error

Tags: iis-7, yii2-advanced-app, php-5.6

******PHP Fatal error Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\advanced\frontend\models\Employee.php on line 2******

What code showing code below is my code while running am getting above mentioned error

```
<?php
 namespace frontend\models;

use Yii;

/**
* This is the model class for table "employee".
*
* @property integer $Emp_id
* @property string $Emp_Name
* @property string $Emp_Gender
* @property string $Emp_Designation
* @property double $Emp_Sallary
*
* @property Empinfo[] $empinfos
*/
class Employee extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
  /**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'employee';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['Emp_id', 'Emp_Name', 'Emp_Gender', 'Emp_Designation', 'Emp_Sallary'], 'required'],
        [['Emp_id'], 'integer'],
        [['Emp_Sallary'], 'number'],
        [['Emp_Name', 'Emp_Gender', 'Emp_Designation'], 'string', 'max' => 45]
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'Emp_id' => 'Emp ID',
        'Emp_Name' => 'Emp  Name',
        'Emp_Gender' => 'Emp  Gender',
        'Emp_Designation' => 'Emp  Designation',
        'Emp_Sallary' => 'Emp  Sallary',
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getEmpinfos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Empinfo::className(), ['EmpId' => 'Emp_id']);
}
```

}

Comment: please suggest the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `Empinfo::className()` is not namespaced

May be something like

```
use app/models/Empinfo;
use Yii;

function rules(){}
```

......